# NavigationDrawer Fragment Header image

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I put the image in a navigation drawer but I can't see.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/ocio"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="otcproject.v1.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();
               // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

The application run and I can see the options navigationdrawer but I can't see the image header.

Comment: Have you tried to give the ImageView a fixed height?

Comment: Yes, I have put a height 150dp and other, but I can not see the image

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `match_parent` of the fragment. Try to set its height to 0dp and the weight to 1 (it will occupy all the available space, that is the same as "`match_parent` minus the ImageView's height").

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="otcproject.v1.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

`match_parent` means that the view will match the size of its parent, then you can not have a view which wraps its content (the ImageView) and another one which match its parent (the fragment). The second one will overlap the first one.